# How "Google Pixel (XL)" activates the "unlimited full resolution photo and video backup"

Tags: google-play-store, google-photos, google-pixel

Google offers Pixel-Phone customers **"Unlimited Full resolution photo and video backup"**. 
Does anyone know how Google handle this?

I can imagine 3 options - but does anyone know which one matches or how it will be handled exactly?

*Three thoughts:*

1. For instance, someone is buying the phone via the Playstore online with his google account and he wants to give it away as a gift.
   Does the unlock only counts for the user who bought the phone?
2. or will it be activated for the person who activates/registers the phone the first time with a Google account?
3. or does this always counts for any further user of the Pixel-Phone? Let's say Google Drive excludes the space-calculation for any picture/video which was taken with a Pixel-Phone?

Comment: Umm... I don't think the "customer" gets that, the device does... Basically if a pic/video is synced to Google Photo by a Pixel device, the space it consumes doesn't count against your account.

Comment: @acejavelin ok - so option 3 would be the one you expect?

Comment: Yes... #3 is my guess... The other 2 options don't make sense. Google has not been forthcoming with this information, and it hasn't been out long enough to figure it out yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Google Product Pixel help](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/phone-by-google/QMjcTzlwMMM)

> **Question:** ....Do you think that the unlimited photo/video backup will be tied to
>
> 1)  a single account,
>
> 2) any account that is signed in on the Pixel
>
> 3) any photo/video with Pixel in the EXIF info or
>
> 4) something else entirely?

This question is pretty similar to what you are asking

> **Answer:** Essentially you can only backup to **one account at a time**. the unlimited storage applies to that account. If you switch the account that you backup to , then the unlimited storage applies to that account.

(Emphasis Supplied)

IMO , applying this to your options

- **Option 1:** Not Applicable - since it is not yet tired to your account, you can buy and gift it to your friend
- **Option 2:** Yes, as long as the person continues to use it
- **Option 3:** Counter starts afresh for new user

While this is not the *official* explanation from Google, it does seem logical

Answer (score 0):

The offer only applies to a single Google account that is signed in on the Pixel, and only photos and video taken on that device is counted under the unlimited quota.