# How Google Pixel owner register the unlimited free storage?

Tags: google-pixel

I have been reading and heard Google Pixel owner get unlimited free storage, but how?
How Google Pixel owner register the unlimited free storage?
I want to know if is register automatically when you buy the phone, or there is some code you can enter.

Answer (score 1):

From [Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/10/04/buying-pixel-phone-means-free-unlimited-photos-storage-pictures-video-maximum-quality/)

> .... When you receive your brand spanking new Pixel and log in with your Google account, the Photos promotion should automatically start.

Related [How "Google Pixel (XL)" activates the "unlimited full resolution photo and video backup"](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/160935/131553)

Comment: That's just how it happens from my experience with my Pixel XL. Also if you go into the Google Photos app, select Settings, then Back up & sync there is a note on that screen saying, "*Full-resolution photos & videos uploaded from your Pixel device will get unlimited free storage*" and there are no options to pick a lower resolution upload.

Comment: @GAThrawn: thanks for sharing first hand experience